# How to avoid Dialyzer errors for protocols?

Tags: protocols, elixir, dialyzer

A simple protocol yields two kinds of dialyzer warnings:

```
defmodule Dtest do
  defprotocol Valid do
    @doc "Returns true if data is in a valid state"
    def valid?(data)
  end

  defimpl Valid, for: Integer do
    def valid?(_), do: true
  end
end
```

The warning I can't figure out is this:

```
dtest.ex:2: The specification for
'Elixir.Dtest.Valid':'__protocol__'/1 states that the function might
also return 'true' but the inferred return is 
'Elixir.Dtest.Valid' | 'false' | [{'valid?',1},...]
```

I also couldn't figure out a `@spec` that'd work here to silence the warning.

The other kind of warning has been discussed elsewhere – many "unknown functions" listed:

```
Unknown functions:
  'Elixir.Dtest.Valid.Atom':'__impl__'/1
  'Elixir.Dtest.Valid.BitString':'__impl__'/1
```

(etc.)

Is there a `@spec` that can be used with `defprotocol`'s? I haven't found any examples. Or, is there a way, in the source code to mark the `defprotocol` to be ignored by dialyzer?

EDIT: Here's the full fix for the first error:

```
defmodule Dtest do
  defprotocol Valid do
    @doc "Returns true if data is in a valid state"
    @dialyzer {:nowarn_function, __protocol__: 1}
    def valid?(data)
  end

  defimpl Valid, for: Integer do
    def valid?(_), do: true
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you take a look and see whether this recently created bug is related? http://bugs.erlang.org/browse/ERL-159

Comment: @aronisstav that's a regression in erlang 19. I'm seeing this in 18, so probably not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using

```
  @dialyzer {:nowarn_function, __protocol__: 1}
```

in the protocol definition for now.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try. Does this fix the problem entirely?

Comment: This fails when I try it:  `{{nocatch,{error,"  Unknown function '__protocol__'/1 in line lib/dtest.ex:1"}}`

Comment: Ah hah, so **within** the `defprotocol`.